# What does the method setMaxFrameSize of the class CameraBridgeViewBase exactly do in OpenCV Java?

Tags: java, image-processing, camera, android, opencv

I am currently using the method `setMaxFrameSize` of the class CameraBridgeViewBase in a android app for down-regulating the captured frame of my main camera. In my use case, I need a very low resolution, because a good performance is needed. I wondered if this method only regulates the output frame, but not the internal captured frame which is altered by different filters.

So my question is: Does this method immediately take the frame after capture and alter it so that the whole processing process is using the altered frame, or does it only alter the frame right before it is shown on the display?

Can you show me where I can find an answer to this matter, or where you found it?

Here is a minimal:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    javaCameraView =(JavaCameraView) findViewById(R.id.java_camera_view);
    javaCameraView.setMaxFrameSize(240, 180);
    javaCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
    javaCameraView.enableFpsMeter();
    javaCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please include a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with your question. Cheers!

Comment: If you need good performance in your app - opencv camera is not what you should be using.

Comment: @DmitriiZ. What would you use instead?

Comment: @RichChurcher Thank you! :) Like this?

Comment: @Pm740 native android camera + GLES to render frame.

Answer (score 1):

**setMaxFrameSize()** is used to find the best preview frame resolution from the device-specific list (returned by [Camera.getSupportedPreviewSizes()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPreviewSizes())).

> As an example - we set setMaxFrameSize(200,200) and we have 176x152 and 320x240 sizes. The preview frame will be selected with 176x152 size.

If your size is too small, **JavaCameraView** will try to setPreviewSize(0, 0) and on most devices it will fail.

Comment: So the preview resolution is the resolition which is shown on display, but not the one which i am working on bevor display the processed image?

Comment: No, it's exactly the resolution you get from the camera. You don't get a pixel more (or less). For display, the picture may be scaled up or down to fit the 'window'. But your onCameraFrame() callback gets inputFrame whose width and height are not allowed to exceed the MaxFrameSize you have chosen (width - 240, height - 180).

Comment: Then a 180p preview frame should have a better perfromance than a 720p one, right?